# function and member function pointers inside arithmetic types

Tags: c++, c++11

For object pointers, we have `std::intptr_t` and `std::uintptr_t` from `<cstdint>`, but those don't need to fit either the function pointers nor the member function pointers. Once could write a metaprogram to find the right fit among the arithmetic types and use the correct alignment, but AFAIK no arithmetic type is guaranteed to fit. One could use an additional level of indirection and use an ordinary pointer to object. One could use an array, say `char[]`, with an appropriate alignment. What does the standard say? Is an arithmetic type, that fits either of the two pointer types, guaranteed to exist?

EDIT:
I need this to pass a pointer into Javascript, disguised as a value of arithmetic type, then pass it back into C++, where I'd convert the value back into a pointer.

Comment: As you said before the question, the answer to the question is no.

Comment: You could try using the largest integer type available and a static assert that it's big enough.

Comment: Use `std::intptr_t` then. That's its job.

Comment: @40two `std::intptr_t` does not need to fit either a function pointer, nor a member function pointer.

Comment: Does your scripting language support integers wider than 64 bits?  Perhaps if you fill in a few more details about your use case we can offer better assistance.

Comment: Does it really have to be a member-function pointer? Would a plain function-pointer suffice? Do your target systems implement common extension function-pointers are compatible to void-pointers?

Comment: @JohnZwinck it is Javascript.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd be satisfied with a function-pointer-only solution, but I cannot rely on any extensions.

Comment: Javascript uses 64-bit floats.  How do you expect to store anything like a pointer in there?  Are you able to use several numbers to store the value, or a string, or...?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: That may be, but no common architecture really uses more that 48 address bits.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well, one possibility would to send it a pointer, cast to a double, but, yeah, it'd be ugly.

Comment: @Deduplicator: sure, you can store one amd64 pointer in a double, but a member function pointer can be two pointers, which definitely won't fit.  So we need more info, such as are you able to store several numbers or not.

Comment: Can you just use a forwarding function? Because extracting the actual function pointer and using it directly [seems to be an extension as well](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html).

Comment: @JohnZwinck Anything javascript can process, so an an arbitrary array of doubles, chars or whatever is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I technically won't answer your question, because I think you're asking the wrong one.

Here are the main problems with what you're doing:

- Never try to store an address directly in an integral data type, you have no guarantee that it'll work.
- Don't store pointers to your data in other places (e.g. files, network, other programs), there's no guarantee that the pointed data will exist when that value is needed.

Store your pointers in a local container and pass around an identifier to the right pointer.

For example, you could use a `std::map<int, boost::any>` for that and give the scripting language the integer key.

This fixes both mentioned issues.

Comment: Storing pointers in an integral type will work with a cast, if the pointer is a standard data-pointer and the integral type is `std::intptr_t`, `std::uintptr_t` or a wider type. Also, passing pointers out and using them after getting them back is ok, though one assumes responsibility for their integrity and normal pointer-invalidation rules still apply. The final advice might be inefficient but is still good.

Comment: Exactly, the only problem could come from a differing alignment between the pointer and the integer.

Comment: @user1095108 You need to look up 'safely derived pointers' -- there is more than just alignment.

Comment: @Yakk Ok, you've answered my question then. I need to use a char array, passed to javascript and then back. A string is the right way to store these 2 pointers. Write an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @user1095108 Sorry -- I don't feel up to doing an answer justice right now.  I'd have to become more than just aware of safely derived pointers and actually understand the rules, and while I want to do that, today is not that day.  ;)  Feel free to do the work yourself, and self-answer!